# Using jQuery, when drop down box changes, I need another input field to become required using Coldfusion

Tags: jquery, input, find, jquery-selectors

I have a form that outputs systems assigned to a project.  The systems are looped and new rows can be added dynamically so using ID attribute is not available.

When the user make a change to the status drop down option, I need the associated Status Effect Date field to become required.  I don't know how to traverse the DOM well enough to locate the field with a class of datepicker.

```
<tr>  
    <th class="form">
        <label>Status</label>
    </th>  
    <td>
        <div style="float:left;">  
        <select class='status' name="status" >  
            <option value="New">New</option>  
            <option value="Existing">Existing</option>  
            and so on...  
        </select>  
        </div>
    </td>  
    <th class="form">
        <label>Status Eff. Date</label>
    </th>  
    <td>
        <div style="float:left;">  
            <input type="text" name="statuseffective" class="datepicker" size="15" >  
        </div>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

If spelled out, the process would work like this:
when a user make a change to the status, JS would find the next input field that contained the class .datepicker and addClass('required') as well as set focus to this field (setting focus is optional since the addClass'required' would already make the field red).

I can determine which drop down box changed, I just cannot get to the next input element.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: solution needs to work primarily for IE.  If solution works for FF, too, that is just an added bonus.  Company standard is IE.

Comment: @locrizak don't even get me started!  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.status').change(function(){
    $(this).next('input.datepicker').addClass("required").focus();
});
```

Should do the trick.

### Update

Ok so... because both do not have the same parent you have to go up a level. next only finds the direct next element, nextAll finds all of the elements (at the same dom level it looks like). Testing a bunch of different ways of doing it and came up with this:

```
$('.status').change(function(){
    $(this).parents('td').nextAll("td:first").find('.datepicker').focus()
});
```

That should do the trick for ya!

Comment: This is almost identical with what I came up with too but it isn't working which only adds to my frustration.  :) `$('.status').live("change", function() {  
    $(this).next('.datepicker').addClass("required").focus();    });`

Comment: @locrizak - I failed to include your name in the previous comment.

Comment: @dlackey updated my answer with a solution. Tested it out and it works for me.

Comment: @locarizak the parent stuff is really confusing to me.  I dont understand when an item becomes a parent or a sibling.  I think if I could master that, the rest would be soooo much easier for me to grasp.  I just seem to have a mental block for some reason.  I going to lunch and will come back and try your solution in a little bit.  Fresh eyes and a full stomach. :D  thanks.

Comment: Look at the indented code you supplied, dlackey. Your select element is a 'child' of the <td> that is wrapping it, which is, in turn, a child of the <tr> (which is likely a child of a <table>, etc.). That means that the <td> wrapped around your select element is the parent. The .datepicker element is a child of an entirely different <td>. To traverse the DOM, you need to ensure that you are moving through the relationships properly.

In addition to children and parents, you also have 'siblings,' which should be self-explanatory.

Comment: @Steve-Costello is this a true scenario with div tags (or at least close - not easy to layout code in the comment section :)  )
`<div id=parent1>
    <span>child of parent1 (also a sibling to other span)</span>
    <span>child of parent1 (also a sibling to other span)</span>
    <div id=parent2>
    <span>child of parent2 (also a sibling to other span</span>
    <span>child of parent2 (also a sibling to other span</span>    
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: I did modify the solution to work with dynamically added rows:
I changed `$('.status').change(function(){` to `$('.status').live("change", function() {`

Answer (score 1):

Here we go... an edit to my answer since I see now that the .datepicker is not under the same parent as the .status.

$(".status").live("click", function(){
 $(this).parent().find('input.datepicker').addClass("required").focus(); 
)};

Comment: That is a new approach that I have not seen before.  Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Comment: Duur. That's because I failed to include the bit of logic that locrizak included above... detecting the actual change of the '.status' element. His/her code should work just dandy.

Comment: @steve-costello I've not seen the two class joined with a + sign before.  Can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: Per http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/, it selects the next adjacent matching element. The caveat here is that they still need to be within the same parent.

Comment: See my new answer... I just saw with your latest code change that the .datepicker is not within the same parent as the .status element. New code I provided should work.